# Swift UI shading only outside of symbol

Tags: swiftui, shading, sf-symbols

Here are two SF symbols, one with some shading.

[image]

As you can see, not only is the outside of the second symbol shaded, but so is the inside. How would I shade only the outside, leaving the inner whitespace white rather than shaded? Ideally a solution would work for other SF symbols, as I'm planning on shading more than just this symbol.

Code:

```
struct exampleSymbol: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "text.bubble.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .font(.system(size: 100))
    }
}

struct stack: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            exampleSymbol()
            exampleSymbol()
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is possible in iOS 15, using a [`symbolRenderingMode(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/symbolrenderingmode(_:)) of [`.palette`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/symbolrenderingmode/palette).

```
       /// Note: This should be capitalized
struct ExampleSymbol: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "text.bubble.fill")
            .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
            .foregroundStyle(.white, .blue)
            .font(.system(size: 100))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ExampleSymbol()
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 3 lines inside bubble icon are white]

For under iOS 15, you'll need to make your own custom icons.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Apple is really adding some great enhancements with iOS 15.

Comment: How would you make a custom icon?

Comment: @JohnSorensen with a vector editing app. I prefer [sketch](https://www.sketch.com/).

Comment: @JohnSorensen btw if the answer worked, can you press the green checkmark to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using iOS 15, you could place a white rounded rectangle behind the icon via a ZStack:

```
    struct exampleSymbol: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "text.bubble.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .font(.system(size: 100))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).frame(width: 80, height: 60).foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            VStack {
                exampleSymbol()
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an image of your result? I tried your approach in my computer and it didn't seem like it worked.